# Using simple class name in java logging formatter

Tags: java, formatter, java.util.logging

I have a SimpleFormatter for logging in my application with the string
 
`"%1$tF %1$tT %4$-7s %2$s %5$s%6$s%n"`

I would like to use the simple class name rather than the canonical name.  Is there a format option I can use with the 2$ field?  Or does this require writing a new Handler?

For example, rather than 
`2019-02-06 07:09:09 INFO    simplex.tools.SIMPLEXScheduler main Start`

I'd like to see 
`2019-02-06 07:09:09 INFO    SIMPLEXScheduler main Start`

Comment: HOw do you initialize your `Logger` with the full class name I suppose. Just put in the simple class name there.

Comment: I use Logger.getGlobal().  I call it from many different classes and it returns the right class name; I just don't want the full path to the class.

Comment: you could use the `logp(Level level, String sourceClass, String sourceMethod, String msg)` method to do your logging calls, passing in the simple class name and a perhaps empty method name, as this builds the `LogRecord`s source entry But I'd rather recommend that you take your time to have a look at the different logging frameworks (skf4j, logback, log4j2 etc.), because they are way more flexible especially when it comes to formatting and controlling the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a format option I can use with the 2$ field?

The [SimpleFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html) only supports the functionality in the [java.util.Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html).  Currently there is no way to format class name as simple class name.

> Or does this require writing a new Handler?

One option is to write a new [java.util.logging.Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/Formatter.html).  There are some hacks that you can do by just installing a [java.util.logging.Filter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/Filter.html) to change the [class name](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/LogRecord.html#setSourceClassName(java.lang.String)) but you should avoid doing that. Use [logp](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/Logger.html#logp(java.util.logging.Level,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) instead as suggested by [P.J.Meisch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4393565/p-j-meisch)

**Disclaimer:** I'm a content developer for [com.sun.mail.util.logging](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/util/logging/package-summary.html) package included with the [JavaMail](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.javamail) project.

If you have access to JavaMail you can use the [com.sun.mail.util.logging.CompactFormatter](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/util/logging/CompactFormatter.html) which will only print the simple class name.  The trade off is that it will print [compact stack traces](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/util/logging/CompactFormatter.html#format-java.util.logging.LogRecord-) for exceptions.  Arguments 1 through 6 are the same order as the SimpleFormatter so the same pattern can be used.

If you don't want to include JavaMail then you can use the [com.sun.mail:logging-mailhandler](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/mail/logging-mailhandler/1.6.3/logging-mailhandler-1.6.3.jar) artifact instead.

Comment: Thanks, I think writing a new Formatter would be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a custom Formatter as suggested by [jmehrens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2428802/jmehrens).  If I need something more complicated I may try moving to another framework like log4j but this does what I want for now.  Thanks for the advice!

```
                Formatter formatter = new Formatter() {
                    @Override
                    public String format(LogRecord record) {
                        String source = "";
                        if (record.getSourceClassName() != null) {
                            try {
                                source = Class.forName(record.getSourceClassName()).getSimpleName();
                            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            if (record.getSourceMethodName() != null) {
                                source += " " + record.getSourceMethodName();
                            }
                        } else {
                            source = record.getLoggerName();
                        }
                        String message = formatMessage(record);
                        String throwable = "";
                        if (record.getThrown() != null) {
                            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
                            pw.println();
                            record.getThrown().printStackTrace(pw);
                            pw.close();
                            throwable = sw.toString();
                        }
                        return String.format(getLogFormat(), new Date(record.getMillis()), source,
                                record.getLoggerName(), record.getLevel(), message, throwable);
                    }

                };
```

Comment: You should catch LinkageError and RuntimeException thrown from Class.forName.  Instead of logging the stacktrace you could just substitute the (record.getSourceClassName().  Otherwise if you run in to an issue with class loading in your current code you'll have the a blank class name.